# Check if toggle is visible or hidden, and remove class if hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two toggles as defined in the code below. I'm looking for a way to check if `search-open` or `nav-open` are hidden, and if they are, `no-scroll` should be removed from `body`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-button').click(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('search-open no-scroll');
    $('body').toggleClass('nav-open no-scroll');
  });

  $('.search-button').click(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('nav-open no-scroll');
    $('body').toggleClass('search-open no-scroll');
  });

});
```

```css
.nav-open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  background: rgba(76, 182, 204, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.search-open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  background: rgba(201, 40, 59, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div>
    <a class="search-button">Search</a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a class="nav-button">Navigation</a>
  </div>
  <br /><br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br /> Content
  <br />
```

Comment: can you please share the html and css ?

Comment: Sure, here's a Fiddle showing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/v74xyrp8/

Comment: As you can see, scrolling works before any of the toggle buttons have been engaged.

Comment: What do you mean by hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is that you are toggling the no-scroll class twice, so it is has no effect. Is this what you are looking to achieve ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-button").click(function() {
    $("body").removeClass("search-open no-scroll");
    $("body").toggleClass("nav-open");
    if ($("body").hasClass("nav-open") || $("body").hasClass("search-open")) {
      $("body").addClass("no-scroll");
    }
  });

  $(".search-button").click(function() {
    $("body").removeClass("nav-open  no-scroll");
    $("body").toggleClass("search-open");
    if ($("body").hasClass("nav-open") || $("body").hasClass("search-open")) {
      $("body").addClass("no-scroll");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.nav-open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  background: rgba(76, 182, 204, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.search-open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  background: rgba(201, 40, 59, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="search-button">Search</a>
</div>

<div>
  <a class="nav-button">Navigation</a>
</div>
<br /><br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br /> Content
<br />
```

Comment: This is better, but I should be able to toggle directly from one button to another and still having the no-scroll class set while one the overlays is shown.

Comment: do you mean if search is open and then i click on navigation, i should see the scroll bar ?

Comment: No, the scroll bar should be 'locked'/invisible if either search or navigation is open :) Sorry about the messy question.

Comment: @TNF no worries, i have updated my answer with what i understood from your comment. Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: This is absolutely perfect! Thanks a lot @PR7 for your help.